# Getting an EntityCollection to talk to the database

Tags: c#, entity

I believe I have found what I want in terms of a main class for operations in Entity, but do not know how exactly to wire it up to the database, and MSDN is precious short on documentation (Google is even less useful).

Again, pardon my ignorance, as I am new to this, and only recently coming up to speed, but how would I get this to connect or reflect this change with the database? I am just not seeing a path between this, and say DbContext. Do I craft a query by hand? Is there some special class I am missing that provides some functionality I've been missing over the last three days that I've been trying to coax this framework into doing just anything minimally useful? Thanks to anyone who accepts this arduous task.

```
EntityCollection<T> newCollection = new EntityCollection<T>();
newCollection.Add(objectValue);
```

I mean, is EntityCollection just a List / Array for Entities? Or does it have some back-end hooks to the database? Can it perform updates / deletes when its methods are called, and are these magical in nature, or is there some prep work that makes the magic work?

Comment: Why don't you try it by yourself? Just do some CRUD operation and see if it's reflected in the DB or DbContext.

Comment: Perfectly honest? It's an inherited project, it won't compile, there are probably a few thousand errors, and I'm looking for anyone with experience to help me get a starting point to cleaning it up. When I say that I do not know Entity, that it is new to me...I mean it I started reading the tutorials earlier this week, and the concepts are still sinking in.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, this `class` behaves just like the [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) `class` - i.e. it's an in-memory collection.

Look at this answer: [ObjectSet.AddObject() vs. EntityCollection.Add()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6585731/952310)

But if you'll look at the MSDN documentation about its [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351713.aspx) method so you'll see that it could be related to the `ObjectContext` and eventually to the data-source(Database):

> The Add method adds an object to an EntityCollection and
>   creates a relationship between the two objects. When the source object
>   is attached to an ObjectContext instance, the Add method also adds the
>   object to the ObjectContext. This operation is translated into an
>   insert operation in the data source when SaveChanges is called. For
>   more information, see Adding, Modifying, and Deleting Objects (Entity
>   Framework).